# Model is not throwing(Saving) data to the backend in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, frontend

This is function for updating user's info.

**views.py**

```
    def UpdateProfile(request):
        context = {}
        user = request.User
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        if request.POST:
            form = PersonalInfo(request.POST, instance=user)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.Save(commit=False)
                user = user.id
                obj.user = user
                obj.save()
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                #messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
                context['personal_form'] = form
        else:
            form = PersonalInfo(instance=user)
            context['personal_form'] = form
        return render(request, 'admission/signup.html', context)
```

This is the model I have created for storing user info.

**models.py:**

```
class ApplicantInfo(models.Model):
    infield = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', blank= True, null= True)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is the form class I have created.

**forms.py:**

```
from .models import Applicant, ApplicantInfo
from django import forms

class PersonalInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileInfo
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'profile_pic',
            #'date_birth',
            'father_name',
            'street_adr',
            'city',
            'zip_code',
        ]
```

This is the frontend template which I have created, this is working fine.

**Template**

```
    {%block content%}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in personal_form %}
                    <p>
                        {{field.label_tag}}
                        {{field}}
    
                    {% if field.help_text %}
                        <small style="color:gray">{{field.help_text}}</small>
                    {% endif %}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
                {% for field in personal_form %}
                    <p>
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <p style="color:red">{{error}}</p>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            </body>
    </html>
    {% endblock content %}
```

**The app has been able to load the form without any trouble but it just not throwing data to the backend.**

Comment: What do you want to Access in templates ?

Comment: i want to store the user data at the backend. that's it

Comment: @AsifIqbal do you not get an error like "ModelForm has no model class specified."? Or if that is not the complete code of your form `PersonalInfo` please add it. Also please add relevant parts of your template to the question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, i am not getting any errors and futher more form is also completed as i have already putted model, fields in the form class PersonalInfo. i am also been able to save user data from admin panel.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i have updated the form code. Please take a look.

Comment: @AsifIqbal as I mentioned earlier please also add relevant parts of your template `admission/signup.html`.

Comment: Please add your `signup.html` in your Question

Comment: As i notice that you didn't acces your 'model` objects in your View .

Comment: @Progam, i am accessing model's object through the form i have created. and i also added the frontend template. Please take a look.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat template has been added, please take a look.......

Comment: I would like to ask by _"throwing data to the backend"_ you mean saving the data when the user submits the form right? Also at least test your code before posting if you modify it. `class Applicant Info` how would this run? Also your form is for the model `ProfileInfo` yet you show some other model... And are you sure the data is not being saved?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat throwing means saving the data, you get it right. and for the extra space b/w Applicant Info, its due to dictionary error here in this form, but in code it is correct syntax, please this type of error, I appreciate your effort , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Updated function for UpdateProfile

**views.py**

```
    def UpdateProfile(request, id=None):
        context = {}
        user_obj = request.user
        if not user_obj.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PersonalInfo(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.save()
                user_id = Applicant.objects.filter(app_id = user_obj.app_id).first()
                obj.user = user_id
                obj.save()
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                #messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
                context['personal_form'] = form
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            form = PersonalInfo(instance=user_obj)
            context['personal_form'] = form
        return render(request, 'admission/signup.html', context)
```

Updated code for forms method, only add #def cleaned_data function

**forms.py**

```
    class PersonalInfo( forms.ModelForm):
    
        class Meta:
            model = ProfileInfo
            fields = [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'profile_pic',
                #'date_birth',
                'father_name',
                'street_adr',
                'city',
                'zip_code',
            ] 
        def clean(self):
            if self.is_valid():
                first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
                last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
                father_name = self.cleaned_data['father_name']
                street_adr = self.cleaned_data['street_adr']
                city = self.cleaned_data['city']
                zip_code = self.cleaned_data['zip_code']
```

And model does not need to be change, you have choice either to add and autofield(PrimaryKey) or use the default one

***The problem was in view.py where i just removed instance attribute from the form object, then I called user_id from user model which is in this case #Applicant model, then assigned to the obj object and saved obj.***

***Thanks to all of you who has spent precious time in this problem.***
***Cheers!!!***